# Permission.Write.Settings only granted to system apps - needed to change screen brightness - will code also work on Google Play?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

My app has to adjust the screen brightness of the phone. To do so, I needed the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Android Studio shows the following error, when I hover over the permission:

```
    Permission is only granted to system apps
```

But: the code still works when I upload it to my phone. Can somebody explain me why? Furthermore, I'd need to know, if this code will also work, if the user downloads the app from Google Play.

Is there a different approach to change the screen brightness?